# Need to add a for loop to an array to create a pop up image

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a school assignment where I have to make five of my array images in my table a pop up using a for loop. I can't quite figure out how to do that. I've included my for and string variables.

I've tried just adding in a basic loop but am not sure how to get the image to pop up.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < cover.length; i++)
{
    str += "<tr><td><img src='" + cover [i] + "'/></td>";
    str +=  "<td>"  + author[i] + "</td>";
    str += "<td>" + description[i] + "</td>";
    str += "<td>" + button[i] +"</td></tr>";
}

for (var i=5; i<cover.length; i++)
string+= "<tr><td><img src="

str += "</table>";

var elem = document.getElementById("book");
elem.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: is the popup on click or how should it function? I feel your question is kind of ambiguous

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Amanda, and congrats on your first question.  This guide might help you get more out of your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 

Is your script working currently?  Have you considered adding a functioning snippet to your code so we can muck around with it and test solutions?

Comment: This might help too: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Hi Tim, so sorry for the ambiguous question. Yes once the image is clicked it should pop up the full size image.